# Trying to index match data from a different workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, index-match

My colleague collects data in Google Sheet A. I want to reference and index-match some of that into my sheet B where I track the progress of projects. I've tried two different ways of doing it, and neither of them work for me.

Here are the two ways I tried:

1. I created a new tab in sheet B. Then I used importrange to sync with the data from sheet A. Then I used index match to reference the data from the importrange in the same sheet. Indexmatch did not work with the importrange data. Only once I copied and pasted it as values, did the data come over, but that of course broke the live synced importrange.
2. I tried to do the `indexmatch` and `importrange` at the same time using this formula from this forum:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("SheetA",Tab"!A4:H26"),MATCH($Cell,IMPORTRANGE("SheetA",Tab"!A4:A26"),0))
```

But that just gave me an error.

Any other ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

use vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1; 'Sheet A'!A:H; 2; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's just schematic, but have you used the quotation marks this way? --> Tab"!A4:H26"

You should use them like this --> "Tab!A4:H26"

And when you write "SheetA" you're writing the Spreadsheet Id, right??

And you should add another comma before the last parenthesis and tell which column you want to grab the final data from (1 for Column A, 2 for column B, etc.)